# How can I force Dukat for generation of declared types?

Tags: typescript, kotlin, kotlin-js

I want to generate kotlin definitions for mobx npm package. For this purpose I use [Dukat](https://github.com/Kotlin/dukat). It's completely generate all interfaces, but ignores all declared constants and functions.

For example:

Generated file content

[image]

Original file content

[image]

How I can force it to generate this for me?

Comment: Hi! Can you be more specific? Unfortunately, Dukat is still not an ideal tool and there's a lot of improvements to introduces and bugs (to fix)[https://github.com/Kotlin/dukat/issues]. However, const are supposed to be translated (as well as external functions of course)